# COLAS EN LARAVEL, Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, email, queue

El problema es que en la cola se manada a la tabla ya migrada, pero al procesar esa cola no termina de procesar nunca por tener cierto error, al verificar el log de `laravel` me di con la sorpresa que era:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

No entiendo por qué, ya que con `send` envía normal pero con `queue` ocurre este problema, dejo el código, espero me puedan ayudar.

**Este es el controlador para enviar los datos al correo:**

```
public function correo(Request $request){
   // return $request->_token;
  //  if($request->ajax()){
      $mensaje = request()->validate([
          'name'=>'required|max:40',
          'email'=>'required',
          'message'=>'required',
          'telefono'=>'required|digits:9',
          'subject'=>'required'
      ]);
   $usuariosdeenvio=DB::table("users")->get();
    $empresa=DB::table("empresa")->first();
    foreach($usuariosdeenvio as $us){
        Mail::to($us->email)->send(new CorreosRpta($mensaje));
    }
   
   return "OK";
  
   // }
    
}
```

**La clase del correo:**

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class CorreosRpta extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $subject="CORREO";
    public $msg;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($datos)
    {
        
        $this->msg = $datos;
        
    
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
       
        return $this->markdown('emails.emailadmin');
   
    }
}
```

**Esta es la vista que genera el error:**

```
<p>Sus datos:</p>
<p>Nombre: {{$msg->name}}</p>
<p>Su correo: {{$msg->email}}</p>
<p>Su celular: {{$msg->telefono}}</p>
<p>Su asunto: {{$msg->subject}}</p>
<p>Su mensaje: {{$msg->message}}</p>
```

**El error:**

> [2020-07-15 23:29:41] local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bluemaxproject\resources\views\emails\emailadmin.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bluemaxproject
> esources\views\emails\emailadmin.blade.php) at C:\xampp\htdocs\bluemaxproject\storage\framework\views\636acbe467b2838af858116767cfe4b5bea92ef1.php:288, ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'name' of non-object at C:\xampp\htdocs\bluemaxproject\storage\framework\views\636acbe467b2838af858116767cfe4b5bea92ef1.php:288)
> [stacktrace]

Comment: Será porque es un array y no un objeto?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Por favor evita abusar de la negrita y de las mayúsculas.

Comment: al parecer la propiedad $msg->name no existe, podrías hacer un dd($mensaje) en tu función correo para ver si estan llegando esos datos.